# Is it possible to protect Get Requests in Spring Boot MVC with Recaptcha (inside the Spring Boot Application)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, recaptcha

Let's say when you send a request to this url: `...?query=something&filter=another_thing`, I am returning a web page with model attribute let's say `model.addAttribute('result', resultList)` then just for loop the result and print the values. (Template resolver could be jsp or thymeleaf, but there is no option to load resultList without model fashion - I mean there is no ajax request - )

What I want to do:

- before loading the result (or loading the page), I just want to load google recaptcha.js first and
- recaptcha will return a token,
- then I will send token to the backend via ajax request.
- After all if request is not bot, I will print the resultList

Is this requirement possible to implement inside the Spring boot application itself?

> NOTE: I could not find anyway to do this. I just though that I could intercept the original get url then redirect to the another page, and this page will load recaptcha and send the token to my backend. If it is not bot then redirect to the original get url. However I do not know how to preserve original request

Answer (score 0):

You're framing it slightly wrong, which may make all the difference.

When making a request, you want to make sure that request is authorized, before you handle
it.

That is where a recaptcha comes in.
To prevent unauthorized access, look into spring-security and recaptcha for that.

Once sufficient authentication has been achieved, your request will then enter your controller, and you can serve the page.

(of course, you could look into it doing it dynamically, but that will be a bit harder)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can not figure out how to get google recaptcha token when I have only get request. (I should somehow stop the user in the get request and and before displaying content I must get the recaptcha token from the google server